# Uniform Sampling points on a line using 2 Uniform distributions

Tags: uniform-distribution, sampling, cumulative-distribution-functions, sampling-theory

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time but I am not sure how to proceed.

So I am given a sampling algorithm : We would like to uniformly sample points on a line between A and B. Start with sampling $x,y$ from $U([0,1])$ (a uniform distribution),then the point $P = \frac{xA + yB}{x+y}$.

For the sake of simplicity I let A=0 and B=1 and generated some results in R to see if the points are uniformly sampled, but they are not. So I would like to understand why this sampling algorithm does not yield uniform samples.

Some Work I have done: I tried looking into some prior questions but I could not find a match. I think finding the cdf and showing its not a straight line (like the one for uniform distribution) would suffice to show that the algorithm does not yield uniform sampling, however I am struggling to find such CDF. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality $A=0$ and $B=1$. We have to verify that $Q=X/(X+Y)$ is not uniform. To this end, we compute $\Pr(X<Yr|Y=y)=1$ if $yr>1$ and  $\Pr(X<Yr|Y=y)=yr$ if $yr<1$ which implies $\Pr(X<Yr)=\int_0^1yrdy=\frac{r}{2}$ if $r<1$ and  $\Pr(X<Yr)=\int_{1/r}^1dy+\int_0^{1/r}yrdy=1-\frac{1}{2r}$ if $r>1.$

This leads  for $0<q<1$ to $F(q)=\Pr(X/(X+Y)<q)=\Pr(X/Y\leq q/(1-q) )$ which is

$F(q)=\frac{q}{2(1-q)}$ and $F'(q)=\frac{1}{2(1-q)^2}$ if $0<q<1/2$,

and also  $F(q)=\frac{2q-1}{q}$ and $F'(q)=\frac{1}{2q^2}$ if $1/2<q<1.$

Comment: Thank you for the response ! It might be a bit dumb but I do not understand what the variable yr is. I am also unsure as to how you make the transition from $Pr(X/(X+Y) < q ) = Pr(X/Y \leq q/(1-q))$. Appreciate the response !

Comment: Sorry I got that the transition $Pr(X/(X+Y) < q) = Pr(X/Y \leq q/(1-q))$ is just algebra so thats all good. Just confused about the $yr$ variable and the first part !

Comment: Well, if $Y=y,$  then $Yr=yr$, I cannot explain more. Also $ \Pr(X<Yr|Y=y)=\Pr(X/Y<r|Y=y).$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the sum $x+y$ will not be uniformly distributed.  You should be able to sample uniformly if you use one uniform variable; e.g.,
$$P = (1-x) A + x B,$$
where $x$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.  Then when $x = 0$, $P = A$, and when $x = 1$, $P = B$.

It's also worth mentioning that $A$ and $B$ need not be limited to $\mathbb R$.  They can be arbitrary points in $\mathbb R^n$, and you will still get a uniform sampling on the line segment joining $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response ! So basically if I were to calculate the cdf of the $x+y$ then it will not be constant right? I think I can use convolution to get the pdf and then cdf to show that.

Comment: @kuuhaku I've already shown you that you only need one uniform variable.  Try it out for yourself.  Let $x$ be uniform on $[0,1]$, and let $A = (2,3)$, and $B = (5,7)$.  Then calculate $$P = (1-x)A + x B = (2(1-x) + 5x, 3(1-x) + 7x) = (3x+2, 4x+3).$$  These will be uniformly distributed on the line segment joining $A$ and $B$.  You can also try to calculate the PDF of $P$ when $A, B \in \mathbb R$.